# Cannot redeclare class + class not found?

Tags: php, class, include

I have had some really strange errors here with php today.

I've written a little class for A/B Testing and wanted to create a new instance in a php document of mine:

```
if(!class_exists('ab_tester')) include('../lib/php/ab_tester.php');
$ab = new ab_tester($user['id']);
```

One would think this should do the trick, but php says:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ab_tester in [PATH_TO_PHP]ab_tester.php on line 10
```

Why does this happen?

Note: Line 10 of the ab_tester.php looks like this:

```
class ab_tester {
```

If I leave the include line out, creating a new instance of ab_tester, it spits out:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ab_tester' not found in [PATH_TO_PHP]returning.php on line 25
```

What do I do now? If I try to import it, it's already there and if I don't, its missing.

Comment: Does `class ab_tester` appear more than once in your class file? Could be the case...

Comment: no, it doesnt. and then the error wouldn't be thrown at the beginning of the file, I suppose :/

Comment: can you show us the first 10 lines of your file?

Comment: Found it.
In the including file (returning.php) waaaay down the code river there was another "include" of the class file.
Sadly the PHP-Debugger Pointed the Error out at the class-file itself. This wasn't helping =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what do the first 9 lines of code in ab_tester.php contain?

I bet that there is another `class ab_tester` there (or in an include, anyway)

EDIT:

Another possible explanation is that you are doing a second include of `ab_tester.php` later on the code of `returning.php`. So even if you use `include_once` in this particular line, the second call is still just an `include`...

Comment: No, not at all. Its containing PHPDoc.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
include_once('../lib/php/ab_tester.php');
$ab = new ab_tester($user['id']);
```

?

Comment: include_once does the same as include => cannot redeclare and so on... I havent seen such a behavior in all these years I'm using php!

Answer (score 0):

Try autoloading classes instead of using includes?

```
function __autoload($class_name){
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = "../includes/{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
}
```